# How to proof the the derivative of $x^2$ is $2x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I need your help, my question is how to proof that the **derivative** of $x^2$ is $2x$?

Please I need a clear explanation.

Comment: Do you know what the definition of the derivative is?

Comment: Please show your effort in the question so that it is good to solve  what your doubt actually was.

Comment: @AsalBeagDubh .. Ya you are correct. What may be easy for one may not be easy for the other. But a little bit of effort on solving the problem must be shown while asking.

Comment: ok .. I shouldn't have said that

Answer (score 13, accepted):

What have you tried so far? If you wish to do it from first principles, then
$$\frac{d}{dx} x^2 = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}$$
Try expanding and simplifying this limit

Answer (score 6):

1st way: Use the product rule and use that $x'=1$. Then $$(x^2)'=(x\cdot x)'=x'\cdot x + x\cdot x'=2\cdot x.$$

2nd way: Use the definition and particularly the difference quotient:
$$ f'(x) :=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2hx+h^2}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} 2x+h = 2x$$

Answer (score 6):

The derivative of a function gives the rate of change of that function at a certain point. If you do not know that $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ is the definition of the derivative then asking for a proof of $f'(x)=2x$ given $f(x)=x^2$ is a pointless question. But if you do then,

\begin{align}
f'(x)&=\lim_{h\to 0 }\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{(x^2+2xh+h^2)-x^2}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{2xh+h^2}{h} \\
&=\lim_{h\to 0}2x+h \\
&= 2x
\end{align}

Or a much quicker way, we use the general formula $$\frac{d}{dx}x^n=nx^{n-1}.$$ In this case let $n=2$ and you wind up with the same answer.

Comment: He was confused probably because the ```h``` is gone in final formula

Answer (score 3):

Take a straight line that passes by the point $(x,x^2)$ of the curve, and a second point close to it, $(x+h,(x+h)^2)$.

The slope of this line is given by the ratio of the $y$ variation over the $x$ variation.
$$m=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}=\frac{(x+h)^2-x^2}{(x+h)-x}=\frac{2xh+h^2}h=2x+h.$$

If you make $h$ smaller and smaller, the line converges to the tangent, with slope $2x$.

Answer (score 1):

The Greeks knew 2 things about parabolas:

- The focus of a parabola is located at $(0, \frac 14)$
- The triangle formed from the focus point $F$, to the parabola at $I$, back to the y-axis along the tangent line to $P$, and from $P$ back to $F$ forms an isosceles triangle:

[image: Parabola focus]

We can combine these two observations to find the derivative without resorting to limits.

We know:

- $F = (0,\frac 14)$
- $I = (x, x^2)$
- $|IF| = |PF| = L$

So $L = \sqrt{ \left(x^2 - \frac 14\right)^2 + x^2 } = \sqrt{ x^4 + \frac 12x^2 + \frac 1{16} } = x^2 + \frac 14$

From this, we find $P$, as $P = (0, \frac 14 - L) = (0, -x^2)$

Now we can find the slope of the parabola at $I$ by looking the slope of $IP$, which is

$$\begin{align}\text{Slope } IP &= \frac{I_y - P_y}{I_x - P_x}\\
&= \frac{x^2 - -x^2}{x - 0}\\
&= 2x
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

f(x + E) = f(x) + Ef'(x) & E^2 = 0 (E is indiscernible)

(x + E)^2 = x^2 + Ex^2'

x^2 + 2Ex + E^2 = x^2 + Ex^2'

2Ex = Ex^2'

x^2' = 2x

Comment: I don't grasp the idea of your post. What does your second identity mean? Could you provide more comments?

Comment: Think of a microscopically small linear segment imposed on a curve; then the first identity holds (hint - rearrange for f'(x)). The second line is just the first identity applied to x^2.

Comment: Is this some kind of Taylor expansion? I doubt the equality there, but now I see your point :)

Comment: It's smooth infinitesimal analysis - didn't want to say it. The E^2 (epsilon) is neglected because we can make E as small as we like; if the epsilons are left in we get finite difference calculus.